# SVG rotate one object on two points

Tags: svg, rotation

i have the following problem:

In my application i can define an image-container. If i rotate the container, the image inside the container will also be rotated (of course). But i can also rotate the image inside the container. So the image will be rotated twice: first on the center of the image-container if i rotate the container, second on the center of the image if i rotate the image.

Is it possible to handle this situation in SVG?

Thanks and keep healthy
Rüdiger.

Comment: Handle what situation. I'm confused. Perhaps if you created a [mcve] with what you're getting and an image of what you want to see instead.

Answer (score 0):

The rotated image-container clips the contained image like this:

[rotated image-container with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRE4n.png)

But inside the container i can also rotate the image like this:

[rotated image-container with rotated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti7SM.png)

I hope the two pictures explain it more precisely. The image inside the container must not be centered to the container!

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern1" width="336.4" height="254.8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <image x="20" y="20" width="326.4" height="244.8" xlink:href="http://bigdaddylin:8880/webdav/pools/image/ahires/52H.jpg" transform="rotate(4,173.2,132.4)" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" width="326.4" height="244.8" fill="url(#pattern1)" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" transform="rotate(4,168.2,127.4)" />
</svg>
```

An rect as image-container and an image inside the container. Image-container is rotated (image also rotates with the container) and the image will be also rotated